# AEM 6.3 Communties CKE editor config local file

Tags: aem

i'm attempting to update the UGC toolbar for a Communities implementation. Based on this: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/communities/using/rte.html I can update the toolbar. Ideally we'd like the ckrte.js to site within our code base. I've tried within our clientlibs in our project folder but that didn't work.

Can this file live local, or will it only work in CRXDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the file and add it to your code base and ensure that it loads after the out of the box clientlib has loaded. They register the rte as "ckeditor" in the JS, your code will override the previous registration. Saves the hassle of modifying the original file that might get changed during upgrades or service pack installations.

Comment: I've done this with the HBS files that drive the Communities front-end, but i can't figure out where ckrte.js file would live.

Comment: You can add it in a clientlib in your codebase that has cq.social.scf,cq.underscore and cq.backbone as dependencies. Then load the clientlib on your page.